# How to allow a small amount of overlap between objects

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I'm working on a project that requires testing of overlap between objects which I have working with the `BVHTree.overlap` function.

The problem is I need the objects to nest a little closer together for a more realistic look.

To this end, I would like to measure the amount of overlap between the objects and keep those that are within a certain margin.

For example if 2 objects only overlap by 0.0-1.0 inch in the scene, then I would keep them instead of removing.

Let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: Have you tried using the `epsilon` parameter when creating the BVH tree (either from an object or bmesh)? See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that parameter. If it can take a negative value that just might work.

Comment: I couldn't get the epsilon value to work with a negative value. I ended up using a bit of hack to accomplish my goals. I reduced the scale of the particles when placing them, and then scaled them back up when complete. This allow more particles to be placed and gave a little more control to the amount of overlap.